# SpringJpa : How can get a list of an object with a field being unique or first

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity class titled Message:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Message")
public class Message extends DefaultEntity {


    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="sender")
    private User sender;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="receiver")
    private User receiver;


    @NotNull
    private String message;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MessageStatus messageStatus;

    private Boolean isRead;
}
```

by the way i removed the getters and setters, so it wouldnt be so long.

I want to retrieve a list of chats where the MessageStatus is "READ" and the Sender is Unique/Last/Latest (because there would be a lot of records between two specific users(sender and receiver)), I want the latest record to enter the DB based on date created.

I tried this, but i am stuck as i dont know how to make the app get a single sender based on the Date created;

```
List<Message> findMessagesByMessageStatusAndReceiver(Enum.MessageStatus messageStatus, User Receiver);
```

so now i have some message enitity persisted into my database like this;

```
{date, sender, receiver} , {2/5/7, 1, 2}, {2/6/7, 1, 2}, {2/8/7, 1, 2}, {2/9/7, 1, 2} , {2/5/7, 4, 2}, {2/5/7, 5, 2} , {2/5/7, 10, 2}, {1/5/7, 10, 2}, {2/3/7, 10, 2}
```

................i want a situation where i can get  all the messages but with a unique record when there are more than one record with the same sender, so in this situation where we have more that one record with the same sender ID : {2/5/7, 1, 2}, {2/6/7, 1, 2}, {2/8/7, 1, 2}, {2/9/7, 1, 2}  only one gets picked based on the recent date and gets added to the list, so {2/9/7, 1, 2} gets picked  and also for this {2/5/7, 10, 2}, {1/5/7, 10, 2}, {2/3/7, 10, 2} this {2/5/7, 10, 2} is picked. so at the end of the day my list is {2/9/7, 1, 2},{2/5/7, 4, 2}, {2/5/7, 5, 2}, {2/5/7, 10, 2}

Answer (score 1):

There are two query methods that you can use for this, the `findFirstBy..` and `findTopBy..`. These two keywords are used to limit the results of a query.

You can check the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) for examples.

Edit

Do a query like this:

`Message findFirstBySenderOrderByDate(Sender sender)`

with which you find most recent record for a sender. Then, from outside you can loop all senders, and call the query method for each one.

Comment: I am not sure you understand the question, i just dont want the first, i want a list of messages with the senders being unique because they where the first picked, based on datecreated or ID

Comment: You should explain better what are you asking.

Comment: so now i have some message enitity persisted into my database like this