# Spring Data JPA: How do i retrieve a list on an entity while filtering its field for first occurrence

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to retrieve a list of all messages from other users (senders) to a user who is a receiver. But i want to only retrieve the first occurrence from each sender.

For example if sender 2 sent 4 messages to user1, only one gets picked(based on the time created) and gets added to the list.

How do i achieve this:

this is my entity class :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Message")
public class Message extends DefaultEntity {


    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="sender")
    private User sender;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="receiver")
    private User receiver;


    @NotNull
    private String message;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MessageStatus messageStatus;

    private Boolean isRead;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringJpa : How can get a list of an object with a field being unique or first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591917/springjpa-how-can-get-a-list-of-an-object-with-a-field-being-unique-or-first)

Comment: Please don't post what seems to be the same question multiple times.

Comment: @JensSchauder then someone should answer the question already